# Facebook Middle name

Tags: facebook

I really want to remove my facebook middle name as it was an old nickname. But I can't. Is there anyway I could get in contact with someone at facebook to remove it for me?

Comment: You can change it under "General Account Settings", it just takes someone on their end to manually verify it, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Under the help settings, there a set of pages that will allow you to contact Facebook regarding these issues.  These are both accessible under [this help page](https://www.facebook.com/help/437470846292890/).

- [Changing your name](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/245617802141709) - a form, if you weren't able to do it under account settings (you must be logged in to access this feature)

and

- [If your name change was mistakenly rejected](https://www.facebook.com/help/103813906377400).